# Internal HDD doesn't get recognized in "My Book" Enclosure on usb. How to format the drive?

Tags: usb, gparted, external-hdd, format

I bought an external HDD: "My Book 8TB". I got the drive out of the enclosure and using that one internally now. I want to make use of the enclosure and put in it a WD Green 4TB. However, the drive does not get recognized. In Windows when I try to format it reads 0bytes and I cannot initialize the drive.

gparted does not list the device at all.

I connected it, via usb 3.0, to my linux computer and ran this command: **dmesg**.

It does somehow get recognized, but I'm not knowlegeable enough to understand what I could do next in order to make the drive work in the enclosure.

https://pastebin.com/b4dCUAJi

Here is the part that clearly lists the device:

```
[  115.900908] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Book 25EE     4007 

PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  115.901337] scsi 2:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       4007 
PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  115.903160] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  115.903769] scsi 2:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 13
[  115.904259] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[  115.917124] scsi 2:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 8
[  115.917129] scsi 2:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
[  115.917131] scsi 2:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[  115.917145] ses 2:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[  116.924214] .
[  117.948229] .
[  118.972049] .
[  119.996215] .
[  121.020038] .
[  122.044239] .
[  123.068210] .
[  124.092028] .
[  125.116227] .
[  126.140204] .
[  126.140369] ready
```

Since the system disk is sda, I thought this one should be sdb. And it is listed like this:

```
[  207.147931] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  207.147933] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  207.147935] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[  207.147937] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
[  207.147987] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  207.147988] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 01 00 00 00
[  207.148004] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[  207.148008] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  207.148203] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  207.148205] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  207.148265] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

So, is there any hope I could configure the drive so I can use it in this enclosure?